# UPDATE ... RETURNING * with large results error

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xl

I am using Postgres-XL (Distributed version of Postgres)

When I run the query:

`UPDATE <table> SET <column> = <value> WHERE <conditions> RETURNING *;`

and the result has about 600-700 rows. Then it works correctly, giving back results -- But if the number of results is in the range of 2000 - 3000 results then I get the error:

`portal "" does not exist`

This happens both from code and the psql command line.

Is there some configuration I can tune that controls how much data I can fetch or any way to increase the number of results I am able to pull from this query. Any pointers will be helpful.